# NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, hibernate-4.x

I have a Play Framework application and I *was* using Hibernate 4.2.5.Final (which is retrieved via the Maven dependency manager).  I decided to upgrade to Hibernate 4.3.0.Final, recompile my application successfully, and ran it.

I got the exception below, and haven't been able to figure out why.  I downgraded back to 4.2.5 and this issue did not occur.  I then, tried upgrading Hibernate with each Final release after 4.2.5.  That is, I went from 4.2.5.Final to 4.2.6.Final, to 4.2.7.Final, to 4.2.8.Final and then to 4.3.Final.  The issue does not occur until I upgrade to 4.3.0.Final.

**Java version information**

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

**And exception**:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:152) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3762) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3716) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
```

Comment: You're calling a method that doesn't exist in the newer version

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I've ran into the same problem. The question here is that play-java-jpa artifact (javaJpa key in the build.sbt file) depends on a different version of the spec `(version 2.0 -> "org.hibernate.javax.persistence" % "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" % "1.0.1.Final")`.

When you added hibernate-entitymanager 4.3 this brought the newer spec (2.1) and a different factory provider for the entitymanager. Basically you ended up having both jars in the classpath as transitive dependencies.

Edit your build.sbt file like this and it will temporarily fix you problem until play releases a new version of the jpa plugin for the newer api dependency.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.0.Final"
)
```

This is for `play 2.2.x`. In previous versions there were some differences in the build files.

Comment: Awesome, it worked!  Thanks.  For future reference, here is a link to documentation for excluding transitive dependencies: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#exclude-transitive-dependencies

Comment: thanks! for maven users: it means just dont use `<groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>`  any more

Comment: For `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` Hibernate `4.2.8.Final` Version is work `4.3.0.Final` also throw an error.

Comment: On Play 2.2.3 
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.3.0.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.0.Final",
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava-base" % "r03",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" %
 "1.3.2"
)` is still throwing NoSuchMethodException
`NoSuchMethodError:javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()`
Anyone knows how to solve?

Comment: Am also facing the same issue with Play 2.3.4 version. Here is the stack trace
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:170) ~[play_2.11-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4
]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4
]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]

Comment: Facing same issue. Added "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.8.Final" and replaced with javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.1-api"),
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"), still having the same issue.

Answer (score 74):

Hibernate 4.3 is the first version to implement the JPA 2.1 spec (part of Java EE 7). And it's thus expecting the JPA 2.1 library in the classpath, not the JPA 2.0 library. That's why you get this exception: Table.indexes() is a new attribute of Table, introduced in JPA 2.1

Comment: I was going down the same track but the code where the error happens is calling `indexes()` on an reference of type `org.hibernate.annotations.Table`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: the error is `NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()`.

Comment: I know, that's why I don't understand it.

Comment: You're probably not looking at the right code, then. See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3.0.Final/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/EntityBinder.java#L936

Comment: @JBNizet Is JPA 2.1 only available in Java EE 7 and not in SE 7?  And I'm guessing JPA 2.0 is available in Java SE 7?

Comment: Update to `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0.Draft-16</version>
</dependency>
            `

Comment: @JBNizet so what is the solution. Can I change to java EE to 7 or can i change JPA 2.0 to JPA 2.1?? If I do so gives error..

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 16):

I update my Hibernate JPA to 2.1 and It works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 14):

You probablly  have 2 different versions of hibernate-jpa-api on the classpath. To check that run:

```
mvn dependency:tree >dep.txt
```

Then search if there are hibernate-jpa-2.0-api and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api. And exclude the excess one.

Answer (score 6):

I could solve the issue simply by replacing the JPA api jar file which is located jboss7/modules/javax/persistence/api/main with 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api'. also with updating module.xml in the directory.

Answer (score 6):

Error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The only thing that solved my problem was removing the following dependency in pom.xml:
    `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>`

And replace it for:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple JPA providers in your classpath. Or atleast in your Application server lib folder.

If you are using Maven
 Check for dependencies using command mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47474708/3333878

Then fix by removing/excluding unwanted dependency.

If you just have one dependecy in your classpath, then the application server's class loader might be the issue.

As JavaEE application servers like Websphere, Wildfly, Tomee etc., have their own implementations of JPA and other EE Standards, The Class loader might load it's own implementation instead of picking from your classpath in WAR/EAR file.

To avoid this, you can try below steps.

1. Removing the offending jar in Application Servers library path. Proceed with Caution, as it might break other hosted applications.

In Tomee 1.7.5 Plume/ Web it will have bundled `eclipselink-2.4.2` in the `lib` folder using JPA 2.0, but I had to use JPA 2.1 from `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.17`, so removed the eclipselink jar and added all related/ transitive dependencies from hibernate core.

2. Add a shared library. and manually add jars to the app server's path. Websphere has this option.
3. In Websphere, execution of class loader can be changed. so making it the application server's classpath to load last i.e, parent last and having your path load first. Can solve this.

Check if your appserver has above features, before proceeding with first point.

Ibm websphere References :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/trun_classload_server.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-create-shared-library-and-associate-it-application-server-or-enterprise-application-websphere-application-server

Answer (score 0):

i have experienced same issue in my spring boot application. after removing manually javax.persistance.jar file from lib folder. issue was fixed. in pom.xml file i have remained following dependency only

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by using `org.hibernate.annotations.Table` annotation instead of `javax.persistence.Table` in the Entity class.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "my_table")
public class MyTable{
//and rest of the code
```