# can't run my web application on jboss server

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jboss

I developed a web project with servlet/jsp and hibernate. It works well on Apache Tomcat 8
but when changing to JBoss 7 server, the following error has occurred and can't run my project with JBoss server

Can anyone explain what is happening ?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.auction.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    com.auction.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
    com.auction.dao.daoimpl.UserDaoimpl.<init>(UserDaoimpl.java:17)
    com.auction.servlet.TestThree.<init>(TestThree.java:17)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory$1.getInstance(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:63)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptor.java:52)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:151)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:76)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>  (WebComponentInstantiator.java:57)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72)
    org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    com.auction.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    com.auction.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
    com.auction.dao.daoimpl.UserDaoimpl.<init>(UserDaoimpl.java:17)
    com.auction.servlet.TestThree.<init>(TestThree.java:17)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory$1.getInstance(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:63)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptor.java:52)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:151)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:76)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init> (WebComponentInstantiator.java:57)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72)
    org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

(**Note:** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.0.CR4 logs.)

This is maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index

Comment: Hibernate 4.3 is JPA 2.1 spec while JBoss 7 provides the JPA 2.0 spec out of the box. If you go up to JBoss 8 you'll likely find that the problem goes away. Or if you go down to Hibernate 4.2.X the problem will go away on JBoss 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue simply by replacing the JPA api jar file which is located jboss7/modules/javax/persistence/api/main with 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api'. also with updating module.xml in the directory.

Comment: Could you also descirbe, at least with a link, how to update module.xml?

Comment: If you placed 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar' in the {jboss7-home}/modules/javax/persistence/api/main/, update the 'module.xml' file like below
`
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="javax.persistence.api">
    <dependencies>
        <!-- PersistenceUnitInfo needs javax.sql.DataSource -->
        <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
</module>
`

Comment: <resource-root path="**hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar**"/>