# Using JPA in JavaFX environment

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use JPA for handling persistence logic. For this I need, I suppose, persistence.xml, which looks like this:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="BookKeeperUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Gamer"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="UserName"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

then I need to import hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.5.Final to my library(using Intellij Idea as IDE) and the mysql driver. Which I also have done.

This is my entity class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "application_user")
public class ApplicationUser {
    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private String passwordhHash;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "name_of_user")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    public String getPasswordhHash() {
        return passwordhHash;
    }
    public void setPasswordhHash(String passwordhHash) {
        this.passwordhHash = passwordhHash;
    }
}
```

and the DAO class:

```
    public class TestEntityManager {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookKeeperUnit");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    public ApplicationUser getAppUserByUserName(String userName){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ApplicationUser appUser = em.find(ApplicationUser.class, userName);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
        return appUser;
    }
}
```

But I get an error that I don't really understand:

```
    jul 08, 2014 8:57:35 EM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: BookKeeperUnit
    ...]
jul 08, 2014 8:57:35 EM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
jul 08, 2014 8:57:35 EM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
jul 08, 2014 8:57:35 EM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Gamer]
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=UserName, password=****}
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jul 08, 2014 8:57:36 EM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at appEntityManager.TestEntityManager.<init>(TestEntityManager.java:14)
    at sample.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:731)
        at
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:775)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:180)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:563)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2348)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2164)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2061)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2778)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2757)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2743)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2730)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2719)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:216)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

So how can I resolve the error? 
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;**

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()\[Ljavax/persistence/Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, after 3 days working on it I finally solved the problem. The main problem was that I was using the library hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.5.Final with java persistence API 2.0 instead of using it with     hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.8.Final. I hope this will help others who may have same problem.