# Hibernate Exception - Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Tags: java, hibernate, pom.xml, hibernateexception

I have tried to establish a hibernate connection with Postgresql, but I'm receiving an exception, as follow:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973)

I saw another topic - ([NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index)) - which explains that I may have two different versions of hibernate-jpa-api on the classpath.

Actually I had, but I fixed that problem and now apparently my classpath contains just one, as follow:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ savedmoney ---
[INFO] com.marques:savedmoney:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.2.12:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.187:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1201-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
```

I still receiving the same exception, and I could not find any solution for it.
See below my pom.xml, hibernate.cfg and hibernate connection class.
If someone can help me, I'll appreciate it.

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dsavedmoney</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.br.savedmoney.model.entity.TUser"/>       
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Hibernate Class Connection**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.marques</groupId>
  <artifactId>savedmoney</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>savedmoney Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>3.5.6-Final</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>savedmoney</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you removed extra jar form your `pom.xml` file if yes did you run `mvn` command again and build project again.

Comment: Hi Joshi. Thanks for your response. Yes, I did and then I have cleaned and compiled the project. I don't know what's happening. As it project is new, I'll try to create another with the correct dependencies. Who knows.. It's technology =D

Answer (score 0):

I created another project with a new pom.xml, with just one hibernate-jpa-api dependency.
Now it's working correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you did not clean the other project properly once you had sorted its dependencies.