# How to Solve Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index; issue in Spring Boot maven Eclipse

Tags: spring, maven, jpa

I have an error

Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

when project deployed in WebLogic 12C with project is configured in Spring boot,maven ad Eclipse.

Here is my POM.XML format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>



<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20080701</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency> -->

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>project</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please let me know any one know the solution.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace. A possible reason for the problem could be that the Java version Weblogic runs on is too old. Another reason could be that a classloader loads javax.persistence.Table from a third party source.

Comment: Your Weblogic probably still uses an old version of JPA. indexes was introduced in JPA 2.1 (Java EE 7).

Comment: Configure your app (or web logic) to prefer classes from the application and not from the server. Weblogic has its own JPA implementation and api and that takes precedence over the classes from the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()\[Ljavax/persistence/Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index)

Comment: Ah, right. The class is not part of Java SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, Spring Boot with Weblogic, I think here you are mixing two web containers (probably wrong approach).
2. Regarding only to JPA exception is because is expecting JPA 2.1 and WLS 12.1.3 has support of it, but not by default. It is necessary to enable it (it is not in the classpath).

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/01-06-004-JavaEE7andWebLogicServer/javaee7.html

Comment: I upgraded to WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0 but the issue is not resolved.

Comment: did you enable jpa 2.1 ? it is not by default.

Comment: how to enable jpa 2.1?? please help

Comment: in the URL given above explains how to enable it: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/01-06-004-JavaEE7andWebLogicServer/javaee7.html

Comment: Thank you for your help..Its Working fine when i updated to WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0 and added dependacies mentioned in the link you provided..Thank you once again.