# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Tags: jpa, nosuchmethoderror

I wrote my first hibernate project exactly as same as my teacher did but I got this exception :

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence
> provider for EntityManager named Sharif: Provider named
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider threw unexpected
> exception at create EntityManagerFactory:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

and I wrote persistence-unit name in persistence.xml file

```
<persistence-unit name="Sharif" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

and I also use Entity annotation in my entity class (Person)
I check almost all Question that relates to my problem but I can't solve it.
project dependencies:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Comment: The error message says `Provider named
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider threw unexpected`; this leads me to believe that the provider was correctly specified, and the problem is somewhere else.
My bet is that you have conflicting versions of hibernate/jpa providers on your classpath. Can you show the list of all your project dependencies?

Comment: @Jakob, it's not a duplicate of the issue you mention. At most, I think it's a duplicate/slight variation of this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index
If you look at the error message you'll see that it correctly detected the specified provider; the message is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Andrei I've just started Hibernate from today I don't know where I can find my project dependencies.I already heard about dependencies in maven project is it right? my project isn't maven

Comment: Sorry, that's why I've said "dependencies" and not "Maven dependencies". Typically any project has a set of dependencies; it is just their format that differs. What are you using to build your project? Just an IDE like Eclipse/IntelliJ/Netbeans? Are you also using an external tool such as Gradle or Ant, or anything else?

Comment: I use IntelliJ. no, I don't use an external tool.

Comment: I haven't used IntelliJ in a while, but maybe this can help you see the list of dependencies : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-tab.html
Then could you edit your question with the list of dependencies? Maybe we can see what's wrong this way.

Comment: @Andrei is this what you want to see?

Comment: almost. Does the `lib` item have any children?

Comment: it's Hibernate libs and no children in dependencies

Comment: try to add persistence-api jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and copy all my code in it. I guess my problem happened because of existing 2 version of `hibernate-core.jar`, this file `hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar` and this `hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar`. I deleted extra jar files and copied new lib folder into the new project and it runs successfully.