# Spring and Hibernate Application with Websphere

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere

I am facing problem in deploying my application to Websphere 8.5

I am trying to build an application with Hibernate 5, Spring 5 and WebSphere 8.5. I am not able to build sessionFactory Object in my project. Not sure where the problem is. Whether wrt to dependency or I did something wrong.

**Here's how I am getting my session.**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/bdcp_01_ORA_XA"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop> 
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

        <!-- The packages that contain our Hibernate model classes -->
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.gssc.model</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate transaction management -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```

**Getting error as Shown below:-**

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation
>   of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

2. Also if I change the version as mentioned above, which version shall i move ahead. And shall i create sessionFactory as mentioned.

Please help

Comment: This answer seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20734660/796761 . And if you're on "traditional WAS" (also known as "Full Profile"), you won't have that level of JPA at version 8.5: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support.html