# Hibernate 5 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.2

I'm trying to test some POJOs with hibernate annotations and I'm getting the same error on and on. I used the same configuration in another project and it all worked fine. I tested the jdbc connection that is used when the hib objects are tested - and the connction works fine.

I have found a few other questions asked about the same error but nothing was helpful.

The code in testing class with main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Item.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

    //create session
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    try {

        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Item> items = session.createQuery("from items").list();
```

The POJO with hibernate annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name="stock")
    private int stock;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    }
```

Below there are getters and setters for each entity.

The file hibernate.cfg.xml has the same configuration as the same file in another project where the connection and hibernate code work perfectly fine - as wrote abobe, the connection was tested in a separate class.

The jars I'm using (all added to class path):

- antlr-2.7.7.jar byte-buddy-1.8.0.jar
- classmate-1.3.0.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.3.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-5.3.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
- javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar
- javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
- jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar

The error that I mentioned in the title mentions a line in my code which is a line in the first code snipet where .buildSessionFactory() occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()\[Ljavax/persistence/Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index)

Comment: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar is added to the class path. The answer given in the questioned mentioned as a possible duplicate does not help to resolve this.

Comment: Question is if there is no conflicting jar with lower version on your classpath. Do `mvn dependency:tree` and check for duplicates, if you are using maven.

Comment: not using maven. all the libs that are used are listed above. how can I find a conflicting jar versions otherwise?

Answer (score 7):

You have conflicting jars in your class path:

- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar

[javax.persistence.Table.indexes](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Table.html#indexes--) is a feature that was added in JPA 2.1.

Therefore you should discard the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar jar because it only describes the JPA 2.0 API.

When you have multiple versions of the same classes available to an application it is difficult to predict which version will be loaded first, which is why it will sometimes appear to work. But it's basically a lottery so you should never do this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because we used resin server and upgraded hibernate

resin has JPA 2.0

and the web application has hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar

this what made the conflicting jars as stated in the `Steve C`'s answer

to fix this case you need to do as stated in https://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0/admin/database.xtp#Hibernate

in resin config file add the new api lib to resin classpath like this

```
<server-default>
    <jvm-classpath>path/to/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar</jvm-classpath>
    ...
<server-default>
```