# Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index, despite using latest version

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Here is my test function/class (I get the error at "session.save(usr)" line):

```
public class MainToTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Transaction trans=null;
    Session session= dbSingelton.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    trans=session.beginTransaction();
    User usr=new User (  "email",  "firstName",  "lastName",  "password");
    session.save(usr);
    trans.commit();
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:828)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at db.dbSingelton.getSessionFactory(dbSingelton.java:12)
at db.MainToTest.main(MainToTest.java:12)
```

Here is my user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="First Name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="Last Name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="Password")
    private String password;
    //setters, getters and constructors
}
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml ( I have used different types of databases (Mostly on remote servers like Azure's) with their proper configuration, and still got the very same error):

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory >
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">%=4b[E6c</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.databaseName">SocialDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <mapping class="db.User" />

</session-factory>
```

Here are my referenced libraries (Extracted from latest version of hibernate (5.4) downloaded from https://hibernate.org/):

[image]

I have found so many topics where the OP solved the problem by using "hibernate-jpa-2.1" (instead of 2.0), and when I added "hibernate-jpa-2.1" next to the libraries above I had the very same exception, however, when I removed "javax.persistence-api-2.2" from the referenced libraries (Since "hibernate-jpa-2.1" had its own persistence classes), I got this exception instead:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/TableGenerators

(There is TableGenerator (Singular) in "hibernate-jpa-2.1" but not TableGenerators (Plural) which only exists in javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar).

When I do not use hibernate-jpa at all I get the same exception mentioned in the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate 5 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573767/hibernate-5-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-table-indexes)

Comment: @Ramy670 What mysql database version do you use?

Comment: @DavidBrossard
Unfortunately it doesn't like I mentioned in the last lines in the post.

Comment: @SternK I tried many different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by letting Netbeans download the libraries itself (By right clicking "Libraries" -> Add Library and choosing Hibernate 4.3 JPA, instead of downloading them from hibernate website.