# Hibernate - No presistence provider for EntityManager named *

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ubuntu, tomcat

after browsing and trying different solutions all across the internet, I came here for help

I have a java project that is working completely fine locally on a Mac (deployed on local tomcat), but when i try to deploy the same war on a Ubuntu server, the request throws  500 with the following trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PERSISTENCE: Provider named org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:833)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:110)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at com.frusoft.schedulemanager.databaseaccess.BaseDao.<init>(BaseDao.java:25)
    at com.frusoft.schedulemanager.databaseaccess.ClientDao.<init>(ClientDao.java:11)
```

I honestly dont know what is the problem here.

hera are my **pom.xml**'s dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

This is the **persistence.xml** which is placed on `src/main/resources/META-INF`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/name?useSSL=false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="usr"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and this is how I instantiate the EntityManagerFactory

```
if (emf == null)
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PERSISTENCE");
```

any kind of help will be much appreciated!

Comment: see if this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index

Comment: This was it!
I remember i tried this in the past, but without success.
The thing is that i needed to perform a mvn clean before the mvn install!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

was getting overwritten by hibernate.
I needed to either remove the dependency or set the newer one that works with hibernate 5.x

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also needed to throw a `mvn clean` command **BEFORE** doing the `mvn install` to generate the .war so that the dependency's no longer cached.

---------- Note ---------

It's still not clear to me why this was working correctly on my local machine (where i developed this backend)

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell `JPA` which JPA provider you are using.

Add `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` to your `peristence-unit` in `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: After adding the provider explicitly (although is not needed), It's still showing the exact same error. Still, this only happen on the Ubuntu VPS i have, locally works just fine!