# How to fix javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I'm developing an application in JSF.
The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1087)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:767)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at w7h5.h8.sf.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:26)
    at w7h5.h8.transaction.TransactionalModule.invoke(TransactionalModule.java:29)
    at abrain.web.common.bean.EditorView.test_post(EditorView.java:112)
    at abrain.web.common.bean.EditorView.setText(EditorView.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.setValue(BeanELResolver.java:122)
    ... 43 more
```

This application is like a Social network and this error occurs when i want to save a new Post.
The method that provide this function is:

```
public void test_post(String testo, String username){

        W7H5 w7db = W7DBS.getInstance();
        Post post=new Post();
        Timestamp data=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        UtentiSocial creatore=new UtentiSocial();
        creatore.setUsername(username);
        post.setCreatore(creatore);

        post.setTesto(testo);
        post.setDatacreazione(data);
        post.setCancellato(false);

        w7db.savePost(post);


        System.out.println("eseguito: " + "testo: "+ testo + "username " + username + "data " + data);


    }
```

i have tried to create a java class test for not passing thought Tomcat (version 8.5) and all work correctly, so the problem occurs when i run the application on server.

I am using:

- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-spatial-5.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar

and

- java version "1.8.0_31"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: What is the hibernate version you use ?

Comment: This does not seem to be JSF related. It simply fails to initialize the Hibernate SessionFactory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()\[Ljavax/persistence/Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index)

Comment: @Selaron unfortunately is not the same, i do not use sbt.

Comment: @RayLloy i have added more information in description

Comment: which java version do you use ? because according to [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/179449/problems-with-hibernate/), `indexes()`  was added for JEE7

Comment: @RayLloy i have added also this information, i am sorry for having omitted them first.

Comment: Is there an additional javax.persistence*.jar in your class path? (e.g. in WebApp or App Server lib folder)

Comment: @Selaron no anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: this is the code of interface table from javax.persistence.ja]

[image: this is the code of interface table from jpa-2.1.jar]

The first image is the source code of interface Table from `javax.persistence.jar`. As you can see there is not the method `indexes()`.

The second image is the source code of interface Table from `jpa-2.1.jar`. And there method `indexes()` is present.

In my opinion, may be you have both jars in your classpath and this create a conflict.
when you call `javax.persistence.Table` we don't know if it is the interface from javax.persistence.jar or jpa-2.1.jar.

Look into your classpath and delete the javaxpersistence.jar, and try again.