# What is a good way to list all dependencies from pom.xml file?

Tags: xml

I am trying to compare pom.xml files from different projects. I plan to make a simple list of all direct dependencies listed explicitly in pom.xml and compare and merge them.

What is a good way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

On the command line:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

See also [List of dependency jar files in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278596/list-of-dependency-jar-files-in-maven)

Comment: This lists the entire dependency tree. Not just the ones declared in pom.xml