# Remove some class file from all jars packaged in tar(each tar is a layer of a docker image)

Tags: docker, jar, log4j, tar, maven-jib

OK so I know how to remove class files from all the jars under a dir. But, now I have different layer from a docker image, each layer is a tar file, and in the tar file there are the jar files.

Can I remove the class files from the jar files, packaged in tar files?

```sh
$ tree -L 3
.
├── 29e0fb8afe376cb02219c977cba1c9a80cca895f7f17b72c356f3e25a63337b9
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── 3b75d6634da4d4f4932d2affeabb7454dc51ba160c3833b386c34e328da8f0ba
│   ├── amq                                               # <<<<< this layer is extracted already, and you can see all the jars here. Other layers are not
│   │   ├── activemq-all-5.11.0.redhat-630495.jar
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── conf
│   │   ├── data
│   │   ├── docs
│   │   ├── examples
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── NOTICE
│   │   ├── README.txt
│   │   ├── webapps
│   │   └── webapps-demo
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   ├── temp
│   └── VERSION
├── c1fa0e994b2d29f60fd2a6caecbe1ac3f987d001903523d60e532b6e08b094f0
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── c8c84a6c1be5bdfc8caafd23082fd725e84f1c9cddb98fd56cad3a62544b2a3c.json
├── ef5088f89fbac64d2d5982ba14492227f60db1221f6bfd6290c6364a2a95a7e3
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── manifest.json
├── repositories
└── script.sh                                             # <<<<< the script is here
```

So you ask me why?
Well, did you hear people talking about log4j recently? :) I am doing this right now: [log4j vulnerability check: how to quickly detect if log4j is used, in mavevn/in an image? "mvn dependency:tree" does not give a full picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333482/log4j-vulnerability-check-how-to-quickly-detect-if-log4j-is-used-in-mavevn-in)

If someone can tell me how to remove these classes from jib maven plugin, that's better. They are from a base image and I doubt we could do that, though.

Comment: You're probably better off updating your Maven or Gradle build to exclude vulnerable versions of log4j everywhere, not just in your Docker images.  I've never had a lot of luck trying to manually edit images as tar files and this probably isn't an approach I'd pursue.

Comment: After some time of trying, I agree with you. Even I can edit layer, change the sha256sum in the main config file, Docker daemon still gives me errors like "Cannot open /var/lib/docker/tmp-xxxx/....: no such file". Seems tempering layers cannot go undetected by Docker.