# how to resolve spring JpaRepository error

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, dependencies, version

I just switched over to the latest version of spring boot 3.1.4 and then started having this issue with using the `JpaRepository`.
I am getting this error that says Cannot access `org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepositor`.
I don't know how to resolve it and I don't want to go back and continue using version 2.7.8 that I was using befor because I am only experiencing the issue while using this new version.
Here is my code

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserModel {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String profileImage;
    private String accessToken;
    private String phone;
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel,Integer> {
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.elijahukeme.onlinelearningappbackend</groupId>
    <artifactId>Online-Learning-App-Backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Online-Learning-App-Backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is really complaining about `org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepositor` then you have typo somewhere in the code.
There is no such class.
There is only `org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository`.

If the exception complains about `org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository`, then something with your dependencies is messed up.

You probably have still an older version of Spring Data Commons on your classpath, which doesn't have that class yet.
But your pom file looks fine, so I suspect that you are seeing this in your IDE and that it didn't fully update it's dependencies.
Therefore a reloading of the maven project into the IDE would be my first try.

If that doesn't resolve the issue I'd start with the following:

- Build the project on the commandline with Maven.
- If that succeeds you need to investigate what is wrong in your IDE setup.
- If the build fails with the mentioned exception, you should inspect the dependencies. I'm sure it pulls in an old version of `spring-data-commons` and you need to find the reason for that. `mvn dependency:tree` should help with that. See [List of dependency jar files in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278596/list-of-dependency-jar-files-in-maven) for more information.